# Deploy multiple .Net Core Web projects in same solution to multiple Azure App services

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

As per the title, we have multiple .Net Core Web application projects in a single solution. In order to deploy these we have to right-click publish on each project and the warm up the sites manually.

I would like to automate this process and assume I can do this via e.g. scripting in powershell? However, I wondered if there would be a way to do this via visual studio configuration, or is the scripting methods preferable in this situation?

I'm not sure where to start with this automation process, searches have not turned up any similar results.

Answer (score 1):

> would like to automate this process and assume I can do this via e.g. scripting in powershell?

Please have a try to use the following code, I test it on my side, it works correctly. More details about `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject` please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/publish-azurewebsiteproject?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

```
Add-AzureAccount

$websitesName = @('WebAppName1','WebAppName2') # website name
foreach ($name in $websitesName)
{
  Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name $name -Package  'C:\Tom\netcoreApp.zip'  # package
}
```

[image]

**How to get the zip file, I test it with Visual Studio 2017.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @PaoloB If it is useful, please mark it as answer that will more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: But how deploy multiple websites in same solution and warm them up?

Comment: `how deploy multiple websites in same solution `On my option,  we could package the each website  in the solution and use loop to do that. `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name $name -Package  $packagePath`

Comment: OK, I tried your approach but got issues I think to do with AppSettings.json but have not had time to look in to it since.

Comment: Could you please share more info about gotten issue?

Comment: Sorry Tom I really dont have time at moment, but will get back to you.